# why defining a method with a return type as its class won't get me an 'incomplete type' error

Tags: c++, incomplete-type

As far as I know when defining a function with an object return type, while the class is only in its forward declaration state like this:

```
class A;
```

// forward declaration, which set **A** as an incomplete type

```
A foo(){...}
```

//error: A is an incomplete type
I know it works fine when it has a return type of a pointer or reference to that object.

But when I define a method with a return type as its class:

```
class B{
  public:
    B foo(){...}
}
```

It works perfectly fine.

I think when defining a method within the definition of class, the class is still an incomplete type.
So I think it will prompt error similar to the former, but it didn't.
Does anyone know why?

I have searched for quite some time before asking for help here.
(I'm not good at English, so my description may get you confused. Sorry for that.)

Comment: It's not an error because you're wrong - `B` isn't incomplete within its own definition. And it's not incomplete because the standard says so (and the standard says so because otherwise it would be really annoying).

Comment: @molbdnilo I think B is an incomplete type, because when I try to define an instance of B inside the definition of class B, I get that error of "incomplete type"

Comment: A's definition is clearly incomplete. What members does it have? But B's definition is complete. It has only one function, called `foo`.

Comment: A has no members, I just made that forward declaration

Comment: The compiler can't know A has no members, B on the other hand has it's definition entirely available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most contexts, you're correct that you couldn't define a function returning an incomplete type. However, the rules have some exceptions to allow the use of a class within its own definition.

It's fine to declare a return type of `B` for one of its member functions even though `B` is incomplete at that point, as specified by C++11 8.3.5/9:

> The type of a parameter or the return type for a function definition shall not be an incomplete class type (possibly cv-qualified) **unless the function definition
>   is nested within the *member-specification* for that class**

It's also fine to instantiate an object of type `B` to return in the function body; within a class definition, the class is regarded as complete in various contexts including function bodies, as specified by C++11 9.2/2:

> Within the class *member-specification*, the class is **regarded as complete within function bodies**, default arguments, *exception-specifications*, and *brace-or-equal-initializers* for non-static data members (including such things in nested classes). Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class
>   *member-specification*.

Answer (score 3):

When defining methods inside a class the class is treated as if it were a complete type, or else we would not be able to define inline methods. Also, if your class A were an incomplete type then the curiously recurring template pattern would not work either. Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T> struct base {};

struct derived : base<derived> {};  // We can use derived here
                                    // without any "incomplete type"
                                    // errors.
```

In other words: it's just the way the language works.

EDIT: See Mike Seymour's below for the relevant section of the C++ standard that mentions this behaviour.

Comment: You are saying when defining methods inside a class, the class is treated as if it were a completer type. Is there any proof of this?

Comment: I don't have access to my copy of the C++11 standard right now, but I'll dig up the relevant section for you when I get home tonight.

Comment: Not a problem. Hopefully between the two answers you have a better picture of what/why C++ does this.